# Parametric function with reference at a central point

Tags: evaluation

Would anyone have any idea how to delete the `xy` and`xyz` steps?

I tried using the `Evaluate` function, but I did not like it...

```
p2={0,125};
P3[α1_]:={-174Cos[α1 Degree]+p2[[1]],-174Sin[α1 Degree]+p2[[2]]};
xy=P3[#]&/@Range[0,360]//N;
xyz=Append[#,0]&/@xy;
Graphics3D[Point[#]&/@xyz]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Graphics3D[
 Point[Table[{0, 125, 0} + {-174 Cos[a], -174 Sin[a], 0},
   {a, 0, 2 π, 2 π/360}]]]
```

or

```
Graphics3D @ Point @ (
   {0, 125, 0} + {-174 Cos[#], -174 Sin[#], 0} & /@ 
    Range[0, 2 π, 2 π/360])
```

or

```
Graphics3D @ Point @ ({0, 125, 0} + {-174 Cos[#], -174 Sin[#], 0} & /@ 
    Range[0, 360, 1 Degree])
```

or

```
Graphics3D @ Point @ ({-174 Cos[#], 125 - 174 Sin[#], 0} & /@ Range[0, 360, 1 Degree])
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the fact that both `Cos` and `Sin` are [`Listable`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable.html):

```
xyz2 = N @ Thread[{-174 Cos[Range[0, 360] Degree] + p2[[1]], 
  -174 Sin[Range[0, 360] Degree] + p2[[2]], 0 }];
xyz == xyz2
```

> True

```
Graphics3D[Point @ xyz2]
```

[image]

Also

```
xyz3 = N@Transpose[-174 Through[{Cos, Sin, 0&/@#&}[Range[0, 360] Degree]] + Append[p2, 0]];
xyz == xyz3
```

> True